# android studio button activity for new screen

Tags: android, android-activity

It's my first app, and i only create hello_world, but I can not make a nickname so that when you click on the button opens a new window , for example, with maps or other information, look here - developer.android.com, there is not such a simple example as I need , tell me how do I make an easy transition to a new page or whether there is an example on the internet with just one button transfer . Or what is my fault , I created a new project and then click , activity, blank activity - then click on the button created in svoeystve Onklikk insert name I created a class, but does not work ...

Answer (score 0):

You should start by reading the docs referring to [activities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). Then you can read about Buttons. Although it is not too difficult to understand you should improve your knowledge.

Additionally you should provide some code or something else that shows that you honestly tried to do something about your problem. If you have question concerning your code the community would be able to help you.